# jsPDF autotable combine cells and format

Tags: javascript, jspdf, jspdf-autotable

I receive data from an API and need to create a PDF table. Each dataset consists of 7 values that need to go into 4 columns. Hence, I must combine them to fit into columns and format them appropriately. I wonder if that works with autotable and jsPDF.

This is my code (the body will be replaced with API data later):

```
doc.autoTable({
    startY: currentHeight + 60, 
    useCss: false,
    margin: 0,
    columnStyles: { 
      service: { halign: 'left', cellWidth: 'auto' },  
      dev: {halign: 'left', valign: 'middle', cellWidth: 30},
      err: { halign: 'left', valign: 'middle', cellWidth: 30},
      amount: { halign: 'right', valign: 'middle', cellWidth: 40} 
    }, 
    body: [
      {
        category: 'Test',
        service: 'Consequatur earum ad numquam minima et qui alias perferendis voluptatem praesentium aspernatur velit omnis qui ut debitis magni iste ipsum.', 
        dev: 2,
        net: 100, 
        err: 19,
        err_amount: 19.00, 
        amount: 200.00 
      },
      {
        category: 'Example',
        service: 'Consequatur earum ad numquam minima et qui alias perferendis voluptatem praesentium aspernatur velit omnis qui ut debitis magni iste ipsum.', 
        dev: 2,
        net: 100, 
        err: 17,
        err_amount: 17.00, 
        amount: 200.00 
      },
    ],
    didParseCell: hookData => {
      console.log(JSON.stringify(hookData.cell));
      if (hookData.section == 'body') {
      switch (hookData.column.dataKey) {
        case 'service':
          hookData.cell.text = hookData.row.raw.category + '\n' + hookData.row.raw.service;
          //console.log(JSON.stringify(hookData.cell));
          break;
        case 'qty':
          hookData.cell.text = hookData.row.raw.dev + '%\n' + hookData.row.raw.net.toFixed(2);
          break;
        case 'tax':
          hookData.cell.text = hookData.row.raw.err + '%\n' + hookData.row.raw.err_amount.toFixed(2);
          break;
        case 'amount':
          hookData.cell.text = (hookData.row.raw.net * hookData.row.raw.amount).toFixed(2);
          break;
        default:
          break;
      }
    }},
    columns: [
      { header: 'Service', dataKey: 'service' },
      { header: 'Deviation', dataKey: 'dev' },
      { header: 'Err', dataKey: 'err' },
      { header: 'Amount', dataKey: 'amount' },
    ],
  })
```

The result is this:

[image: This is what I get with the code]

And this is what the desired table looks like:
[image: This is what I want]

My main problems are these:

- I get the matching fields where I need them with the didParseCell hook, but the line break does not work. Why is that?
- When I merge the two fields in one cell, I can no longer change the styling for only the category or percentages (bold + line height). Is that even possible?
- The last header should be right aligned. Why is that?

Answer (score 0):

After some more deep dives, I solved the problem. For anyone who might have a similar issue, the autotable module is not meant for this purpose. Although it can create nice tables from almost any amount of data you throw at it, it is not meant to format table cells in a custom manner.

I build a custom template with pure jsPDF that formats the data precisely as needed. Autotable can format a single cell, but it cannot format data within a cell. Thus, I created custom cells by calculating the height and positioning of the data where it should be. Then loop through the source and build row after row.